# Is it possible to log function(cities) return value to console in JavaScript for testing whether the output is correct?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am busy with a challenge and I know the code is correct as it passes the assignment but I'm having a tough time testing the out put.

```
<code>
function nonMutatingSplice(cities) {
  // Only change code below this line
  return cities.slice(0, 3);

  

  // Only change code above this line
}

console.log(cities)

const inputCities = ["Chicago", "Delhi", "Islamabad"]
nonMutatingSplice(inputCities); 

</code>
```

When I initiate the console log() call, the output to the console returns "ReferenceError: cities is not defined"

How can I console log the return value of the function to return the correct mutated array's values?

I am expecting to see the following in the console to validate that the code is returning the correct output:

["Chicago", "Delhi", "Islamabad"]

Comment: Assign the result of `nonMutatingSplice()` to a variable and log that. You'll probably need it in a variable anyway assuming you actually use the result somewhere.

Comment: Hi there could I please ask for an example?

Comment: What's the point of `nonMutatingSplice()` given that it doesn't emulate the `splice()` function at all, and always returns a predefined subset of the input Array? This isn't meant as a criticism, but I'm trying to preempt subsequent questions in which you might need to insert new Array elements, or delete elements, at particular indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `log` the output from `nonMutatingSplice`

`cities` is never defined, because you don't allocate a value to the variable.

You can do it by using the following code.

```
const cities = nonMutatingSplice(inputCities);
```

Here's the code with a working output.

```js
function nonMutatingSplice(cities) {
  return cities.slice(0, 3);
}

const inputCities = ["Chicago", "Delhi", "Islamabad"]
console.log(nonMutatingSplice(inputCities))
```

non-mutable example:

```js
function nonMutatingSplice(cities) {
  return cities.slice(0, 2);
}

const inputCities = ["Chicago", "Delhi", "Islamabad"]
const cities = nonMutatingSplice(inputCities);
console.log(cities) //[ 'Chicago', 'Delhi' ]
console.log(inputCities) //[ 'Chicago', 'Delhi', 'Islamabad' ]
```

Comment: I get that but now doesn't that mean I am mutating the original array?

Here's the assignment below:

Rewrite the function nonMutatingSplice by using slice instead of splice. It should limit the provided cities array to a length of 3, and return a new array with only the first three items.

Do not mutate the original array provided to the function.

Comment: No, that will not mutate the original `array` since we are `returning` a value.  I have edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: It's a little confusing as the original array provided is: 

const inputCities = ["Chicago", "Delhi", "Islamabad", "London", "Berlin"];
nonMutatingSplice(inputCities);